# Unpacking two parameter packs by threading their elements to pairs of types

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming

Given say `N` user-specified types, I'd like a function to return a `std::tuple` of length `N` where each element is constructed via a function call to some function (exemplified by `func` below):

```
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>

template <typename T> 
T func(int x)
{
    return T();
}

template<typename... T, std::size_t... I> 
std::tuple<T...> build_tuple()
{
    // How do I write this in a generic way?
    return std::make_tuple(
        func<std::string>(0),
        func<int>(1),
        func<int>(2)
        );

    // This won't work, obviously
    // return std::make_tuple(func<T...>(I...));
}

int main() 
{
    build_tuple<std::string, int, int>();
}
```

Essentially, my question is how do I unpack arguments to get something along the lines of "type0, 0", "type1, 1" etc., instead of "type0, type1, ..., 0, 1, ...", if that makes sense.

This feels like a common problem, so is there an idiomatic solution?

Comment: Do you mean like `std::make_tuple(func<T>(i)...)`?

Comment: @WeaktoEnumaElish Not quite I guess. What I mean is that in comes any number of types that get paired with `i`. For concreteness, an example is that in comes `int, int` and out goes `func<int>(0), func<int>(1)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `size_t` arguments are `0, 1, ...`, you can simply use additional level of indirection:

```cpp
template<class Tuple, std::size_t... I> 
Tuple build_tuple_impl(std::index_sequence<I...>)
{
    return std::make_tuple(
        func<std::tuple_element_t<I, Tuple>>(I)...);
}

template<typename... Ts> 
auto build_tuple()
{
    using Tuple = std::tuple<Ts...>;
    return build_tuple_impl<Tuple>(std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Ts)>{});
}

// Usage:
auto t = build_tuple<std::string, int, int>();
```

More general case:

```
template<class Tuple, std::size_t... Is, std::size_t... I> 
Tuple build_tuple_impl(std::index_sequence<Is...>, std::index_sequence<I...>)
{
    constexpr std::size_t is[] = {Is...};
    return std::make_tuple(
        func<std::tuple_element_t<I, Tuple>>(is[I])...);
}

template<typename... Ts, std::size_t... Is>
auto build_tuple(std::index_sequence<Is...> is)
{
    static_assert(sizeof...(Ts) == sizeof...(Is));

    using Tuple = std::tuple<Ts...>;
    return build_tuple_impl<Tuple>(is, std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Ts)>{});
}

// Usage:
auto t = build_tuple<std::string, int, int>(std::index_sequence<3, 4, 5>{});
```

Not that you can't write `build_tuple<std::string, int, int, 3, 4, 5>()`. One of the sequences should be packed into a single type.